# Plotly as png in knitr/rmarkdown

Tags: r, 3d, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

The following Rmarkdown renders the plotly 3D graph in HTML, but not in PDF.

````
Testing plotly

```{r}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data=iris, x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width, z=~Petal.Length, 
             color=~Species, symbols=c(0,1), type="scatter3d", mode="markers")
p
```
````

A snapshot of the graph appears as follows:

[image]

According to the [plotly help page](https://plot.ly/r/knitr/):

> If you are using rmarkdown with HTML output, printing a plotly object in a code chunk will result in an interactive HTML graph. ***When using rmarkdown with non-HTML output, printing a plotly object will result in a png screenshot of the graph.***

Is there a way to render the plotly graph in a PDF?

*Note:* The error from `rmarkdown::render()` is:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

Answer (score 10):

I have created a little workaround, which saves the plotly images locally as png-file and imports it back to the RMD file.
You need the package `webshot`, which you can load via:

```
install.packages("webshot")
```

Further more, you need to install phantomjs via

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

Then (when phantomjs is in your PATH), you can create your RMD file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy / pop)

tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
export(p, file = tmpFile)
```
![Caption for the picture.](`r tmpFile`)
````

This works for me .. perhaps it's a workaround for you, too!

Comment: I am currently doing the same, but am getting images with a big text error in the middle: "WebGL is not supported by your browser - ...". Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I should clarify - I'm getting the WebGL error when trying to generate a PNG from a 3D scatterplot (not shown in my question)

Comment: Your code works for the 2D data, but not 3D. Thank you! My question has been updated to reflect the challenges with 3D scatterplots (more relevant to my code)

Comment: WebGL [is not supported](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) by Phantom. You'd need to use firefox or chrome for the rendering (IIRC `webshot` does not support using other drivers).

Comment: @hrbrmstr  what does that mean, can you explain how we do this?  This is a pretty serious issue

Comment: What its says. I'm pretty sure the phantomjs project takes pull requests as does the webshot project.

Answer (score 3):

As @hrbrmstr commented, `export()` previously didn't support WebGL at all, but more recent versions support exporting to png via RSelenium (see `help(export, package = "plotly")`). If you need pdf export, you'll have to pay for a cloud account -- https://plot.ly/products/cloud/

Comment: Seems that the dev version currently in GitHub (currently 4.5.6.9000) isn't ready yet, as running `export()` just yields a blank image.

Answer (score 1):

What I do so that rendering to PDF's work but you can still have the interactive plots in other knit types and in rmarkdown files in r studio is:

this goes in the setup block (or really, anywhere early in the file):

```
is_pdf <- try (("pdf_document" %in% rmarkdown::all_output_formats(knitr::current_input())), silent=TRUE)
is_pdf <- (is_pdf == TRUE)
```

then this is used to render any plotly plot based on what kind of document you are creating:

```
if (is_pdf) { export(base_plot) } else {base_plot}
```

in the example `base_plot` is the name of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with [R markdown compile error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543206/r-markdown-compile-error?answertab=votes#tab-top). You need to choose what format you want to KNIT to, tried to look at mine.

```
---
title: "<img src='www/binary-logo.jpg' width='240'>"
subtitle: "[<span style='color:blue'>binary.com</span>](https://github.com/englianhu/binary.com-interview-question) Interview Question I"
author: "[<span style='color:blue'>®γσ, Lian Hu</span>](https://englianhu.github.io/) <img src='www/ENG.jpg' width='24'> <img src='www/RYO.jpg' width='24'>白戸則道®"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html:
    toc: yes
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
  tufte::tufte_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
link-citations: yes
---
```

[image: KNIT]