# kableExtra error in Markdown when rendering to PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, kableextra

It seems that I am having trouble using `kableExtra` when trying to create a PDF by rendering an Rmd-file from an R Script. I have had no success in trying to follow the instructions at:

[R markdown compile error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543206/r-markdown-compile-error)
https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/440
https://community.rstudio.com/t/rendering-both-pdf-and-html-is-only-possible-interactively-not-via-script/19520/3
https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/301

I'll access the packages from the script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(tinytex)
```

Make the Rmd-file:

```
---
output: pdf_document 
---
{r, comment = NA, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}

tibble(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3) %>%
    kable()
```

Render the Rmd-file from the script using:

```
render('C:/Users/Rasmus/SO/Test.Rmd',
    output_file = "Test.pdf",
    output_format = 'pdf_document',
    output_dir = 'C:/Users/Rasmus/SO')
```

This gives me a PDF with a table. But if I start out by running `library(kableExtra)` alongside the others, and then apply the rendering procedure, I get a PDF with:

```
x
y
z
1
2
3
```

After running `library(kableExtra)`, I have tried the rendering procedure on the following Rmd-file:

```
---
output: pdf_document 
---
{r, comment = NA, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}

tibble(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3) %>%
    kable() %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = 'scale_down')
```

This returns:

```
output file: Test.knit.md

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

What is stopping me from using `kableExtra`?

Comment: I was experiencing a similar issue with rendering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538467/knit-rmarkdownrender-producing-different-results-kable-format-pdf/63137364#63137364

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to explicitly add `format="latex"` within the kable function (for example, `kable(format="latex")`) when using kableExtra with kable for PDF output. See [the `kableExtra` introduction](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra#basic-usage) for additional information and examples.

The [`kableExtra` PDF output Vignette](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) indicates that you don't need to set `format="latex"` for version 0.9.0 or later, but I've found (using version 1.1.0 currently) that I still need to set `format="latex"` or I get html output by default.

You can run `options(knitr.table.format = "latex")` at the beginning of any script or `Rmarkdown` document to make latex the default output for that R session and avoid having to add `format="latex"` to each individual `kable` table.

Comment: I ran into the same problems until I saw this answer, thanks so much for this tip - even more than 2 years later. It saved a lot of time & unnecessary recoding.