# Knit & rmarkdown::render() producing different results (kable format; PDF)

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I have some Rmarkdown documents I am trying to `knit`/`render`as **PDF** files.  I want to get `render` to work properly because I am going to run this in a script with multiple Rmd files as well as a lot of other processes (e.g. data grabs & processing).

Using the `knit` button produces the desired result.  If I use `rmarkdown::render` the table layout goes wacky (*see example*). Here's a minimal example that has reproduced my issue.

**RMD**

````
---
title: "RmdTest"
author: "TTS"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: true
---

```{r Rmd-Setup, include=FALSE}
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

library(kableExtra)

# Dummy Data
df <- structure(list(Location = c("Farm", "Farm", "Farm", "Farm"), 
    Animal = c("dog", "cat", "cat", "cat"), Age = c("Adult", 
    "Juvenile", "Adult", "Total"), Abundance = c(27269L, 62308L, 
    34904L, 97212L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```


## Why?

The 'Knit' button is producing the desired result, while running rmarkdown::render is producing a different (undesirable) result.

```{r Table-1, echo=FALSE}
kable(df, caption = 'This data does not make sense.', booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = 'scale_down') %>%
  landscape() %>%
  add_footnote(label = 'Here is a footnote.') 
```
````

**Render**

```
  rmarkdown::render(input = 'test.Rmd', output_format = "pdf_document")
```

**Versions**

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Rmarkdown v 1.1
kableExtra v 1.1.0
```

**Desired Outcome:** To get `render` to have the same output as the `knit` button, specifically the table formatting.  Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if any other info would help.  Cheers!

**Screenshots**

[image: Using Knit]

[image: Using Render]

**New Strange Behavior**

After restarting my R session by exiting and restarting RStudio, I am able to run the `render` successfully, with the desired formatting.  Attempting to run `render` again immediately after is returning the error message: `! LaTeX Error: Environment landscape undefined.`

However, if I use `.rs.restartR()`, `render` produces the incorrect formatting.  Running the `render` afterwards produces the same result: produces a PDF with the incorrect formatting.

**Note:** I reinstalled tinytex this morning to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: When I run your code, the knit button and `rmarkdown::render` produce exactly the same result. Can you post screenshots of the issue?

Comment: Pictures loaded.  Also adding a new behavior description.

Comment: My table output goes wacky too just like your, when I do \usepackage{fancyhdr}. It wasn't always like this though.

Comment: I just ran it a second time and it worked. so unconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the correct packages for Latex in the YAML preamble. I'm not sure why selecting the Knit button in the Rstudio UI and using the `render` function work differently; but they do.  I have found including the Latex packages usually fixes the problem.

```
---
title: "RmdTest"
author: "TTS"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: true
---
```

Comment: Further Explanation: It appears that the added LaTeX packages need to be present for the `render` function to recognize and include them, while the `knit` button apparently recognizes the need for those packages even if they aren't included in the YAML.

Comment: The clue was given in the error message `! LaTeX Error: Environment landscape undefined` and by adding `keep_tex: true` to the YAML.  If you look at the `.tex` file it should now include the the packages `pdflscape` and `booktabs` when it didn't before.