# R markdown pdf, some output won't show

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

So I decided to convert my html R markdown file to a pdf knitr and I noticed that half my code output won't show. I replicated a small example here:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Brandon Morgan"
date: "1/19/2021"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    df_print: paged
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 7
    highlight: tango
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
html_document: 
    code_folding: hide
    csl: biomed-central.csl
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    number_sections: yes
    theme: sandstone
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
---


# TEST

## Data

```{r}
data = iris
head(data)
```
````

Here's my html knitr output:

[image]

Here's my pdf knitr output:

[image]

Notice how `head(data)` does not show for pdf output

Comment: Could you post code? not image. It is more easy for reproducible.

Comment: @JuanCamiloRiveraPalacio I've simplified my problem with the edits above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick fix: remove `df_print: paged`. I can't tell you why it would not produce the result you want at the moment.

````r
---
title: "Test"
author: "Brandon Morgan"
date: "1/19/2021"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 7
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  html_document: 
    code_folding: hide
    csl: biomed-central.csl
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    number_sections: yes
    theme: sandstone
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
---


# TEST

## Data

```{r echo=FALSE, results=TRUE}
data = iris
head(data)
```
````

Comment: I did that and got the error: `Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output` in my main Rmd document.  Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543206/r-markdown-compile-error, just had to include `always_allow_html: true` to the bottom and it worked

Comment: @notMyName interesting, thanks for sharing!